# Jquery post reCaptcha value

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#btn').click(function(){

            $.post('testing.php', {
                email:form1.email.value,
                //recaptch  
            },
            function(output){
                $('#output').html(output).show();
            }); 
        });
});
```

I have a form use jquery post and use reCaptch. How can I post reCaptch's value?

`//recaptch:form1.recaptch...` something, I don't know how to post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thx guys, I have just find out how to do it!

```
recaptcha_challenge_field:form1.recaptcha_challenge_field.value,
recaptcha_response_field:form1. recaptcha_response_field.value
```